# How can I customize the default navigation details provided by Mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have followed the [sample example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/examples/basic/) to implement navigation feature in my app. In the app, the user is navigated to two locations: pickup and delivery. Following is the screenshot of the map.

[image]

The Mapbox SDK provides details of the navigation like distance, time remaining etc (as indicated by red rectangle in the screenshot above). The SDK is considering the overall route and generating these information, by default.

Is there a way to customise these details? Initially, I would like to show the distance and time remaining to the first location. And with the arrival of the user to the first location, I would like to update the information with that of the next route. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes, this doable.

Comment: @Magnas Could you please refer the related documentation that would enable me to accomplish this?

Comment: It starts here but they seem to be trying to dissuade developers from going down that route. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/v0.30.0/custom-navigation.md  I’d contact Mapbox directly for more help. They are very responsive to requests for info.

Comment: @Magnas Thank you. I have emailed to Mapbox support team regarding this, looking forward to getting their response.